# Phaser Dom Ui alignment is off

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

[image]

all things out of alignment and not on scene

im using the `this.add.dom().createFromCache('ui');` method, along with
`this.load.html('ui', './src/scenes/Ui.html');`

UI html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Phaser boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.52.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha512-HqxHUkJM0SYcbvxUw5P60SzdOTy/QVwA1JJrvaXJv4q7lmbDZCmZaqz01UPOaQveoxfYRv1tHozWGPMcuTBuvQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">1</div>
      <div class="column">2</div>
      <div class="column">3</div>
      <div class="column">4</div>
      <div class="column">5</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I face the issue of having no Of the bulma style show up, and the alignment makes the content off website

Comment: Can you specifiy the problem more? Since this works for me as expected. I don't understand what the image is showing? **btw.:**  for better alignment you should/can set the position in the  `dom` method.

Comment: can you add a codepen example

Comment: The issue for me is that no styling shows up, and i thought all the dom was meant to be inside the phaser scene, Why is it outside that?

Comment: Update, I realised i can move the from Cache from the dom(x,y), but how do i setup the ui in scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [official demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/dom-element/form-input) that shows the whole process.

Nevertheless there are just some things to watch out for:

1. in the `config`, have the properies: `parent` and `dom` set
2. when setting the `dom` gameObject, set the `x` and `y` position, and the origin *(with `setOrigin`)*
3. in the **html** you are loading, be sure to set the `width` and `height` of the HTML fragment you want to display. *(this you **don't have** to do, but makes things much easier)*

***The short answer:** the official example works because it doesn't use `css` the change the size of the `canvas`, as your posted example clearly does.*

> **Info from the comments:** Based on the posted code in the comments, and if I understand the issue correct. The issues has to do with resizing the canvas with `width:100%` *(in the html page)*. The loaded html is inside the scene *(theoretically it is inside the canvas area)*, BUT scene stretches over the whole width, so it can seem that i *"exits"* the scene (the background image).

> **Tipp:** For resizing the phaser application you should use phaser features like: with the config `mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT`, or so ([check out the documentation for details](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scale.ScaleManager.html)), since using CSS for formating leads to problems, since phaser doesn't *"know"*, that you are doing this.

Comment: Even in the phaser lab, its on scene

Comment: but when i replicated the examples, elements are out of scene, how can i make sure every element is inside the scene? Is there an option or do i have to set everything by absolute measures?

Comment: @VatsaPandey If you don't share **your** code it is impossible to find/solve your problem(or a [minimal reproducable demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Since in the official demo, everything works as intended, even if you change the `width` of the scene to `300` you will see only a partial form.

Comment: minimum repro: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/vaulted-gilded-turner

Comment: @VatsaPandey well if I understand your problem correct. The issues has to do with resizing the canvas with `width:100%` in the html page. The loaded html is inside the scene, BUT scene stretches over the whole width. for resizing the phaser application you should use phaser features like: in the config `mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT, or so, since using CSS leads to problems.